# CISC, RISC and anything else?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu

Is there a processor architecture that falls outside the CISC and RISC categories?

I'm vaguely familiar with RISC and CISC; my research thus far indicates that either a processor is RISC or CISC, with CISC comprising a large number of architecture types. From [the wikipedia article about CISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computing):

> The term (CISC) was retroactively coined in contrast to reduced instruction set computer (RISC)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computing)[2] and has therefore become something of an umbrella term for everything that is not RISC...

Wiki isn't a perfect resource, but the Google Scholar papers I'm finding don't discuss the architecture types in broad terms. Hoping someone can help clarify!

Comment: VLIW architectures, transport-triggered architectures, and dataflow architectures would generally not be considered RISC or CISC. I would consider stack-based ISAs as outside RISC/CISC, but that is a bit more debatable (the "register" specification constraints exclude such from RISC but some stack-based ISAs are very RISC-like, not fitting the higher variability in work per instruction and bits per instruction more typical of CISC). [John Mashey's definition of RISC](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~vijay/mashey.on.risc.html) is worth reading.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Add references and make an answer?